# Is it really necessary to flip the kernel in a conv-net?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

If I have a software implemented convolutional network and the weights are trained via back propagation, is it really necessary to "flip" the kernel? Afterall I am applying the "unflipped" weights (eg in a 3 x 3 filter) in the same order going both forwards and backwards?

Or have I misunderstood this? Here - look at the demo - http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ - the filters appear to be applied, going forward, unflipped, yet the author says (unfortunately without any further discussion): "The backward pass for a convolution operation (for both the data and the weights) is also a convolution (but with spatially-flipped filters)."

Yet should they not also be flipped, if we are strictly following the correct procedure, going forward also?

My thinking is that, so long as I account for this properly in the "full" convolution, a flip is redundant.

But I dare say I am wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the 1D case: suppose we convolve the input `L = [a b c d e]` with filter `[x y]` resulting in output `Q = [ax+by bx+cy cx+dy dx+ey ex+?]` (We ignore the last entry to avoid thinking about padding). Now consider $\frac{dQ}{dc}$. It is `[0 y x 0 0]` -- the kernel is flipped.

If the error is E(Q), then consider $\frac{dE}{dc} = \frac{dE}{dQ}^T \frac{dQ}{dc}$. If we write $\frac{dE}{dQ}$ as a vector `[f g h i j]` then $\frac{dE}{dc} = gy + hx$. Extending this a bit, it is not hard to see that $\frac{dE}{db} = fy + gx$, and $\frac{dE}{dd} = hy + ix$. In general, $\frac{dE}{dL}$ is the convolution of $\frac{dE}{dQ}$ with the filter `[y x]`.

Extending this to two dimensions means that instead of reversing the kernel, you flip it both ways, since the kernel is now a two dimensional matrix.

Formally, if the input is matrix $I$, the kernel is matrix $K$ of size $n$ by $n$, and the output is matrix $O$ with error being $E(O)$ such that we have the matrix $\frac{dE}{dO}$ then we can write the following:

$$
O_{xy} = \sum_{u,v = 0,0}^{n-1,n-1} I_{x+u, y+v} \cdot K_{u,v}
$$

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x,y} \frac{dE}{O_{x,y}} \frac{dO_{x,y}}{dI_{ij}}
$$

Now we can substitute in:

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x,y} \frac{dE}{O_{x,y}} \frac{d\left(
\sum_{u,v = 0,0}^{n-1,n-1} I_{x+u, y+v} \cdot K_{u,v}
\right)}{dI_{ij}}
$$

Pulling the sum out

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x,y} \frac{dE}{O_{x,y}} 
\sum_{u,v = 0,0}^{n-1,n-1} K_{u,v}
\frac{
 dI_{x+u, y+v}
}{dI_{ij}}
$$

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x,y} \frac{dE}{O_{x,y}} 
\sum_{u,v = 0,0}^{n-1,n-1}
K_{u,v} \cdot  \mathbf{1}(x+u = i, y+v = j)
$$

The indicator function term is only ever true if $x+u=i$ for some $u$ from $0$ to $n-1$. This means that $u-i$ is between $-i$ to $n-1-i$ so that $x = i-u$ is between $1+i-n$ and $i$. The analogous holds true for $y$

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x,y = 1+i-n, 1+j-n}^{i,j} \frac{dE}{O_{x,y}} 
K_{i-x,j-y} 
$$

Now set $x' = x-i+n-1$ and $y' = y-j+n-1$ to get

$$
\frac{dE}{dI_{ij}} = \sum_{x',y' = 0,0}^{n-1,n-1} \frac{dE}{O_{x'+i-n+1,y'+j-n+1}} 
K_{n-1-x',n-1-y'} 
$$

Notice that the subscripts on kernel $K$ are decreasing with $x'$ and $y'$, which indicates that the kernel is flipped for the convolution.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{dE}{dc} = \frac{dE}{dQ}^T \frac{dQ}{dc}$ ie include the transposition? Where did that come from?

Comment: The transposition is just an easy way to condense the sum: $\frac{dE}{dc} = \sum_i \frac{dE}{dQ_i} \frac{dQ_i}{dc} = \frac{dE}{dQ}^T \frac{dQ}{dc}$

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on your statement: "In general, dE/dL is the convolution of dE/dQ with the filter [y x]"? What would the stride and padding of this convolution be? I have asked a similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351807/padding-and-stride-in-backpropagation-of-a-conv-net