# Padding and stride in backpropagation of a conv net

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation, convolution

I am trying to implement the back-propagation of a simple convolutional network. Specifically I understand that one of the steps is the convolution of the gradients coming from the next layer, with the rotated kernels. However I cannot compute the parameters of this convolution. Let's see this with an example:

Imagine that the layer's input is an image of size `(heigh, width) == (4, 4)` with only 1 color channel. We also use `zero-padding == 2` and `stride == 1`. Our kernel (let's say we only have 1 kernel) is of size `(filterHeight, filterWidth) == (2, 2)`. We can now use the following equation to compute each dimension of the output:

`out = (in - filter + 2*padding) / stride + 1`      (**1**)

So the output volume has a `(height, width) == (7, 7)` and everything is fine.

Now comes the time for the backward pass. I need to convolve this `(7, 7)` tensor with the rotated `(2, 2)` weights and get a tensor of `(4, 4)`. How can I compute the stride and padding? I only have one equation (**1**) but two unknowns! Therefore there isn't a single solution for `stride` and `padding`!

I can heuristically find that the combination of `padding == 2` and `stride == 3` will work out, but why choose this over the potentially infinite number of valid combinations?

Comment: Next time, plz post the answer to your question, especially if you went into so much depth on a complex question that a lot of other people are wondering the answer to.  Thanks for asking the question well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you would need to perform a "full" convolution during the backpropagation step. So the gradients from the l+1 layer will be a `(7, 7)` tensor. The "full" convolution with the rotated filter `(2, 2)` will result in a `(8, 8)` tensor. Removing the original padding as added to your input `(4, 4)` would again result in a `(4, 4)` tensor. There would be no need to calculate or guess any further padding/stride while doing the backprop convolution.